# Implementing a different style text view

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, textview

Please have a look at the following image.

[image]

This is a text view which I need in my next android app. However, I really don't know how to implement this kind of textview. I only know how to put a normal rectangle style textview. So, how can I achieve this? If textview is not possible, what are other options?

Comment: Create a 9-patch image and set it as the background http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

Comment: Answer edited. I've added a simple 9patch to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to create an image (a 9patch would be perfect) and put your text over it.

I did a little image for you. Give it a try:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-Ax5zr61_Dvb2QwcmtWUml1Q2s/edit?usp=sharing

Otherwise you can use a Layout that will wrap your TextView (with the rectangle background) and the image of the little triangle below.

You can also try to "paint" it (using Canvas I guess), but seems overkilling to me.